# hgwebdir push - directory empty?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, ubuntu-server

I set up my "mercurial_server" [as follows](http://phpfour.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-central-mercurial-server-in-ubuntu/) (except I used hgwebdir.cgi instead of hgweb.cgi) and I created a repo

```
hg init
```

then I create a local repo work on my code and then push my updates to the server (tortoisehg), they show up on the web, but not in the actual directory? Is this supposed to happen I cant find a write up on the database

Comment: hgwebdir.cgi was retired with Mercurial version 1.6 -- a year ago.  The hgwebdir.cgi that ships with mercurial has completely replaced its functionality -- it does both what hgweb.cgi and what hgwebdir.cgi used to do.

Comment: @Ry4an: hgwebdir.cgi was replaced by hgwebdir.cgi??

Comment: err, replaced by hgweb.cgi.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. The repository (.hg directory) contains the change history you pushed. The working copy is still empty.

To update your working copy to a version from the repository, you need to run the "hg update" command on your server (use the "-C tip" argument to show the latest). This will make the files appear in the directory next to your .hg directory.

In most cases, you do not need to do that on your server unless you are implementing a continuous integration/deployment process.

Comment: ok thats great, I understand, hmm thats a useful feature (wheels turning)

Comment: Perfect answer.  The other piece I'd add is that it's *good* to keep no checkout in the hgweb server because otherwise you'll find someone has made live edits there that never got checked in any repository.  You can remove the working dir from any mercurial respoitory with `hg update null`.